# Problem starting Simulator after doing a reset of skins

Tags: codenameone

I did a reset (and re-download of the skins) in one app, but now my other app fails with this message:

```
Failed loading the skin file: /iPhoneX.skin
```

I *have* downloaded the iPhone.skin in the other app (I realized the old iPhoneX skin I had didn't support the safeArea).

The Simulator won't start with this issue, and despite searching, I haven't managed to figure out how/where to fix it.

Not sure if the "/" before the skin name is what is causing is the problem?

Comment: Try opening Codename One Settings for this project and updating the project. Depending on the version it could be an update menu on the right hand side or under Basic -> Update Project Libs. This specific file is builtin to JavaSE.jar which should be there. If it isn't can you clarify what do you mean by reset/re-download? What exactly did you do?

Comment: I had used the Simulator menu Skins / Reset Skins, and then More to add them again. Not sure if this caused the issue since I also tried deleting the old skin files manually in the file system.

Comment: Did you do an update on the project? What's the version that appears on top of your Codename One Settings app?